# ajax and codeigniter code for add to cart button

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

iam new to codeigniter and to ajax so i need to add a product to cart 
the isert function is working and the button changes to 'remove' but when refreshing the page it again changes to add to cart in need to remain it as 'remove' pls help

```
    $('.btn_add_remove_cart').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var self = $(this);
    if (self.hasClass('add-cart')){ 
        // if it's add cart button, replace add-cart class by remove-cart and change label
        self.removeClass('add-cart').addClass('remove-cart').text('Remove');
    } else {
        // it's remove cart button, do the inverse
        self.removeClass('remove-cart').addClass('add-cart').text('Add to Cart');
    }
});
});
```

this my ajax code 
and my button is

```
<button name="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary add-cart btn_add_remove_cart btn-default promotion-button" value="<?php echo $row->prod_id;?>">add as promotion product</button>
```

Comment: thank u for your advice

Comment: any one knows the answer

Comment: Maintain $_SESSION variable for that so when it gets refresh the cart button still has the product and shows Remove

Comment: thanks but not working  any other answers

Comment: You have to implement that partially in backend. Save state of the cart to session as suggested by @Gurria (http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html), and when you load the page again you should also create the view such that user can see he still has items in the cart (by initializing button to "Remove" state probably).
Take care that when the user removes the item from the cart you remove it from the session variable too.